# Canon Pixma iP7250 - how to install and print with wifi?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, canon

I got a Canon Pixma iP7250 printer. It does show up and work with just plugin the cable, but I want to print without cable using wifi.

I found drivers download on [Canons homepage](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/inkjet/pixma_ip_series/pixma_ip7240.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(32-bit)#disclaimer). Do I need to install them and how do I install them? And how do I make the printer connect with the wifi, cause the cd only has program for pc and mac.

Answer (score 1):

The key is knowing the printer's IP address. Here are instructions to find it: http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/pixma_printer_wireless_connection_setup/ip7250_printer_wireless_connection_setup/

If your router allows DHCP reservations, it is helpful to reserve the address you found for the printer so that the address will not change.

Now open System Settings > Printer. Select  Add. Select Network Printer and see if the printer is found. If not, enter its URI:

```
ipp://192.168.0.4:631/lpr/
```

Substitute the IP address you found for 192.168.0.4 above. 631 is the port used by the CUPS printing system. Press Forward and select the driver and save. We know that your Ubuntu version has the correct driver since the printer works when directly connected. Save, close and print a test page.

Comment: I did have to do one more step, I added it like an answer in my post. :) Thank you so mutch, you saved my week! :D

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! I did follow your step, it didn't work first, untill I realised that I had to check **Publish shared printers connected to this server** in **System -> Administration -> Printing** menu. Now it works like a charm. Thank you. :D

Answer (score 1):

Inserting ip address (ipp://192.168.1.130:631/lpr/ in my case) didn't work for me even when the printer showed up on my routers list of devices under that ip address. Although I could install the printer that way, it did not 'enable', when checking the 'enable' checkbox and clicking apply it just unchecked it!

What worked for me was:
- add network printer -> network printer -> select 'Find Network Printer', but keep the 'Host:' address bar empty and click 'Find' button.
The printer then showed up in the left column under 'network printer' and you can select it and continue.